# How to retrieve parameter from url?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have one table formed in a web page which consists of different items.I am fetching those information from firebase with this code:-

**JS**

```
function ondemand(){
  alert('Welcome');
  var user=firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    var fbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Sell_Products");   
fbRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var key=snap.key;
    //alert('HEllo');
    var name = snap.child("name").val();
    var price = snap.child("price").val();
    var category = snap.child("category").val();
    var description = snap.child("description").val();
    var image = snap.child("image").val();
    $("#ex-table").append("<tr><td><a href=\"auction.html?itemKey="+key+user+"\"><img src=" + image + "/img></a></td><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" + description + "</td></tr>" );
});}
```

I am passing two values i.e key and the user's uid who is currently logged in when a user clicks a particular row. In the next page i have code to retrieve the parameters from the url.I want to retrieve user's uid how can i do that?

For fetching information in next page i am making use of this code.

**JS**

```
var myParam=location.search.split('itemKey=')[1];
alert(myParam);
firebase.database().ref('/Sell_Products/'+myParam).once('value').then(function(snapshot)
{var name=snapshot.child('name').val();
alert(name);
var image=snapshot.child('image').val();
var category=snapshot.child('category').val();
var description=snapshot.child('description').val();
var auctionprice=snapshot.child('auctionprice').val();
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
document.querySelector('#image').src = image;
document.getElementById("category1").value=category;
document.getElementById("name").value=name;
document.getElementById("auctionprice").value=auctionprice;
document.getElementById("description").value=description;
});
```

Comment: yes, but my question is how to retrieve that particular information in my next page.

Comment: the userid who is currently logged in

Comment: i have this is as itemkey TO3H8ugvWPOjUGYAnJX5fYO4MJE2_qualcoume3Z0CTNP3Ocgv3cfCDgd93gBk8LW2 which is passed along url and it consists of three information first TO3H8ugvWPOjUGYAnJX5fYO4MJE2 second qualcoume third 3Z0CTNP3Ocgv3cfCDgd93gBk8LW2

Comment: i want to retrieve third info

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged in and since he is authenticated, then to retrieve the `userid` in any page do this:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var id=user.uid;
```

more info here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users